# Trying to get every 6th set of 4 bytes from a python array

Tags: python, performance, array, numpy

I have an array of bytes 6144 bytes long. I want to extract a set of 4 bytes every 6th set of 4 bytes . So every 24 bytes I want to extract 4 of those bytes and join them in a new array. So
`arr=[a0, a1 ,a2 ,a3 ,a4 ...a6143]` should become
`arrNew=[a0, a1, a2, a3, a24 , a25, a26, a27, ...a1020, a1021, a1022, a1023]`

I have done this by using

```
# data holds 6144 bytes
    j=0
    n=0
    ll=bytearray()        
    while(n<256)
       ll.extend(data[0+j:4+j])
       j=j+24
       n=n+1
```

This works but is too slow for what I am trying to do. Is there a faster way to do it. I was hoping one line of numpy could do it but I couldn't find anything that would work so easily.

Comment: The code as provided has some syntax errors, and so it is impossible for it to run. Please provide your actual Python code. Also you're currently not using numpy, so the numpy tag is unneeded and misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your formatting is bad, adhere to PEP8 for readability.
- `j` is always `n * 24`, so you could eliminate one of them. I'd probably use `j` exclusively.
- Instead of manually iterating an integer in a while loop, use `range()`. In particular, check out the third argument to it.
- Since you know the final size of `ll`, you could allocate the required amount of storage up front and then fill in the parts. As it stands, every rotation of the loop requires making a new allocation for storage, copying the existing data over and release of the old storage.